# Is there a RIGHT approach for securing data further by doing an IP match?

Tags: node.js, express, security

So here is an approach I was thinking of:

PROBLEM:
- after you have done everything possible to secure your servers and client app. I wanted to add an extra layer to make sure even if a user looses access to their data, they can only really affect their own little space in a shared database. (obvisouly authentications are in place but this is the basis of the authenticatino model)

SOLUTION I HAD IN MIND:
- I wanted to add a "hidden" field that stores users IP addresses. 
This means when a user does the normal password and usenrame entry, they also have to verify whether the machine they are using is their own, and thus we store that IP address by taking it from their request.
Later if they need to log in again they can, but if they want to retrieve data, the look up on the router server will recieve the IP from the request, add that onto the message as part of the filter parameters.
Once it queries the database if the combination of IP + data that users wants is found then it sends that back.

If a different IP is detected then no data exists in the server so nothing is sent back. which would initially be done on login and would trigger a mail to the user to verify the machine they are using is trusted.

Is there an easier way? is this overegging?
Thanks,
Alex

Tried ip-request module in Express, works fine, but wanted to know if there was a potential security threat with the way I am using this and it will be implemented before proceding.

Comment: Checking ip is never a guarantee of user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

First off, an IP address your server sees is often not the actual IP address of the computer the user is on because there is often a NAT device or proxy in between that maps a private network IP address of the user's machine to a public IP address for use on the internet.  This would be true whether you were using a computer on your home network, using a computer at work, connected via WiFi at Starbucks, etc...

```
User Computer (private IP 192.168.1.x) => Gateway (some public IP address) => Your server
```

If the same computer connected to your server the same way over and over, it "might" be assigned the same public IP address every time it does so.  But, in other circumstances it might not.

If the same computer is mobile at all (phone, laptop, tablet) and connects to the internet in different ways (WiFi, cellular), then it may show as a different IP address every time it connects from a different location.

So, in these days of lots of mobile devices and a user that may even access a service from more than one device, an IP address is just NOT a good measure of whether this is a risk or not.

Furthermore, in the case of shared NAT such as a WiFi hotshot or connecting from a corporate network, it's possible for lots of different users to all appear to be coming from the same public IP address.

I would not suggest using IP address at all as any security indicator.  You will just get lots of false indicators of an invalid IP address that changed since last access and you may even get false positives where a different user appears on the same IP address as a legit user.  In these days of NAT and mobility, there is no one-to-one correspondence between a public IP address and a user.  Trying to pretend there is will cause all sorts of problems.